# Using reduce to get a sum of object values, but the answer is a few decimals short (JS)

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have the following code:

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {

    // Move cid into an object
    var cashReg = cid.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        prev[curr[0]] = curr[1];
        return prev;
    }, {});

    // Total money in the register
    var regSum = Object.values(cashReg).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);

    return regSum;
    // --> 335,41
}

checkCashRegister(19.50, 20.00, [
    ["PENNY", 1.01],
    ["NICKEL", 2.05],
    ["DIME", 3.10],
    ["QUARTER", 4.25],
    ["ONE", 90.00],
    ["FIVE", 55.00],
    ["TEN", 20.00],
    ["TWENTY", 60.00],
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]
]);
```

The code itself seems to be working just fine, but for some reason when I return regSum the answer is 335,40999999999997 instead of 335,41. Why does this happen and how could I change my code so it would return the expected outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as Geuis sayed it is the number precision problem. If you expected the outcome only retains two digits after the decimal point, you can change "return regSum;" to "return Number(regSum.toFixed);".
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {

```
// Move cid into an object
var cashReg = cid.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    prev[curr[0]] = curr[1];
    return prev;
}, {});

// Total money in the register
var regSum = Object.values(cashReg).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}, 0);

return Number(regSum.toFixed(2));
// --> 335,41
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the javascript number precision problem. Read more here [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to get around this is to scale you numbers. So for $1.50, you could have 150(cents), and do your math based on that, and remember to multiply by 0.01 before displaying. I know that may be a pain, but that's javascript. If it's going to be too much of a change to do that, you could always use a library, such as decimal.js. You can read the docs [here](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/).